# Finally got collapsible styling to apply to XML-generated data but data-icon not applying

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

Using this code/method, I have finally got JQuery Mobile collapsible styling to be applied to data pulled from an XML file - but I can't get ALL Jquery styling to work, such as the icon, which doesn't work. I want data-collapsed-icon to be set to arrow-u, for example. This works in static code, but not when I'm working dynamically with an XML/JSON file. Any ideas how I get the icon styling to work?

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />

<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
$.ajax({
type: "GET",
url: "jargon.xml",
dataType: "xml",
success: function(xml) {

var container = document.getElementById("catalogue");
container.setAttribute('data-role', 'collapsible-set');
container.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'true');
$(xml).find('release').each(function(){
var release = document.createElement("div");
release.setAttribute('data-role', 'collapsible');
release.setAttribute('data-collapsed', 'true');
var cat = $(this).find('cat').text();
var title = $(this).find('title:first').text();
var artist = $(this).find('artist').text();
var tracks = "";
$(this).find('track').each(function(){
tracks = tracks + $(this).find('title').text() + "<br>";
});
release.innerHTML = "<h3>" + cat + "<br></h3><p>" + artist + "</p>";
container.appendChild(release);

});

var catDiv = $('#catalogue');
catDiv.find('div[data-role=collapsible]').collapsible({theme:'b',refresh:true});
}
});
});

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me for not combing through your code to find the relevant element, but here's what I think the issue is:

You need to call jQM's `trigger("create")` method on the parent element that contains the elements with the jQM data attributes.

Here's what the code might look like:

```
$("#myElement").trigger("create");
```

That will apply jQuery Mobile functionality and styling to all child elements of the selected element.

Answer (score 0):

Before you append the collapsible, change `collapsedIcon` and `expandedIcon` options.

```
release.collapsible({
    collapsedIcon:"arrow-d",
      expandedIcon:"arrow-u",
        theme:"b"
    }).appendTo("target_div);
```

> [**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/jWfT4/)